# Utility to move windows as a group for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, windows, group

Is there a utility for Mac OS X that will group windows (2 separate apps)? Similar to how objects are grouped in PowerPoint or other design apps. I would like both windows to move together.

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 apps on the App Store that match the search term "arrange windows" and I have heard good things about three of them (in reverse aplhabetical order):

- [WindowTiler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windowtiler/id439626225?mt=12)
- [Cinch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cinch/id412529613?mt=12)
- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)

The one I use is also on the app store, but doesn't show in that search term but it's fabulous.

- [Divvy](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy/id413857545?mt=12)

Comment: bmike, thanks but "arranging" windows is not what i need. i would like to "group" windows so they drag together. Divvy looks interesting nonetheless

Comment: Yowsers - stacking them and moving them - or tiling them and moving them? I'll edit the beginning of my answer since it's clear none I've listed does grouping across apps. Let me know if you'd prefer I delete my answer so your question sits here unanswered...

Comment: Tiling and moving them. I don't think you need to to delete it since the checkmark indicates a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

X-Assist.
However it seems to be an old app.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the app or screenshots?